# How do I get Python Spyder output to show entire output

Tags: python, spyder

Im using the corr() function on my dataset but the output is only showing the first 2 columns and the last 2 columns. How do I get it to show all the columns 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z96vJ.jpg)

Comment: Images of code is not recommended...

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own custom print function, but for the most part printing out large arrays of data into the console is not the best way to view them. Either export them as a CSV or use the built-in variable explorer in Spyder.